# Mediawiki Extension CategoryTree subcategory example

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Looking for example using categorytree. Using example shared only able to create one level. Not able to add subcategory. Could any one please share the subcategory example.

```xml
<categorytree mode="pages">Manual</categorytree>
```

```
Manual
    Authentication and login
    Customization techniques
    MediaWiki as a content management system
        Manual:Ajax
        AuthPlugin
        Manual:Creating pages with preloaded text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1 Install extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryTree#Usage

Step2 add [[Category:Manual]] in page.

Step3 Create category if does not exists.

Step4 add category [[Category:Manual]] in another category page [[Category:Authentication and login]]

Step5 add {{#categorytree:Manual|depth=5|mode=all}} in a page where you want to add category.